# Filter Lookup from another lookup

Tags: list, lookup-column, column, filter

I have a list of projects. 
Inside the project list you can select a Client.
I have a list of Clients.

I have another list, a list of Contacts, they have a lookup column called Client to specify from which Client this contact is from.

In my project list you can select a Client, i want to be able to also select a contact that is from the list of Clients that was selected.

How can i managed this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a cascaded lookup field.
I suggest you code one yourself or buy one from the net.

Answer (score 0):

You can build cascading lookups via javascript and spservices.  In fact, spservices recently introduced the [SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation) function.

Codeplex offers a cascading lookup solution as [spcd](http://spcd.codeplex.com/) , but [StratusForms](http://www.itunity.com/community/stratusforms) can do this too and you don't need server side access.

Now, there is also a thing called [Sharepoint Filtered Looku](https://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/)p which can perform a lookup via a CAML query; I'm trying to bascially make a cascading lookup [out of that here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163537/caml-query-for-filtered-lookup-column).