# caml query for filtered lookup column

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, caml-query

My project uses the [2010 version](https://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com/) of the [Sharepoint Filtered Lookup Field](https://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/), which has the option to filter a column using a caml query.

So I have three lists: *Categories*, *SubCategories* and *MainList*.

*Categories* is just a plain list.

*SubCategories* is a list with two columns: `Title` and `Category` where `Category` is a regular lookup column leading to the *Categories* list.

*MainList* has a column for `Category` and for `SubCategory` - but `SubCategory` is supposed to filter on `Category`.

So I want to write a CAML query that filters the `SubCategories` list.  It should show only those SubCategories where [Title] is equal to the Category.

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Category"/>
            <Value Type="Text">[Title]</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    </OrderBy>  
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, as it turns out, this cannot be done with the FilteredLookup addon.  You cannot add the current value into the query via variables, which is what I expected you could do with the `[Title]` code in my example.

[Here is where the authour says](https://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com/discussions/254900) it doesn't work that way.

This is too bad; it would make for wonderful functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try like this:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Category"/>
            <Value Type="Lookup">[Title]</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    </OrderBy>  
</Query>
```

> Default lookup query uses the value instead of lookup Id
>
> The typical query looks like
>
> ```
> <Query>
>     <Where>
>         <Eq>
>             <FieldRef Name='RefCountry'  />
>             <Value Type='Lookup'>India</Value>
>         </Eq>
>     </Where>
> </Query>
> ```
>
> To query by ID you have o setup `LookupId='TRUE'` attribute of
> `FieldRef` element
>
> ```
> <FieldRef Name='RefCountry' LookupId='TRUE' />
> ```
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms442728(v=office.15).aspx
>
> ### [Ruslan Dayanov](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119156/caml-query-get-item-by-lookup-value-not-by-id)

Comment: It seems you have missed something from the question. **OP** needs to compare two columns of the list. Generally CAML can compare columns with some values!

Comment: No, I think he is right; problem is that he assumed what I assumed, that the addon would allow for the current variable to be inserted.  See my answer where I have found out it doesn't work that way.